# Minipage - space between two columns and aligning

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, minipage

Here is the deal. I want both of them starting from the very same line and perhaps increase the distance between them. I really cannot remember wheater s.th. chaged after adding `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Berlin}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  


    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \title{3D-Lithography}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Advantages of 2-PP to 1-PP}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
     \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
      Basic Problems of Single-Photon Polymerization:
      \begin{itemize}
      \item layer-by-layer type of manufacturing (limits possible geometries)
      \item suppression through undesired quenching of radicals
      \item diffraction limits
      \end{itemize}
     \end{minipage}
    \pause
     \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
       Optimization by Two-Photon Polymerization:
       \begin{itemize}
       \item true 3D-Process (random geometries) 
       \item radical quenching avoided
       \item small excited spots\\
      $\Longrightarrow$ smaller structures possible
     \end{itemize}
     \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Use `[t]` option in both minipages (this will align them at top), and put a `\hfill` after the first `\end{minipage}` (this will insert as much space as possible between them).

Answer (score 5):

As JLDiaz mentions, you can control the vertical alignment of `minipage`s with an optional argument. Another way would be to use `beamer` `columns`. Both are demonstrated below. Note the `[t]` for the `columns` environment, which top-aligns the columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  


\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title{3D-Lithography}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Advantages of 2-PP to 1-PP}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  Basic Problems of Single-Photon Polymerization:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item layer-by-layer type of manufacturing (limits possible geometries)
  \item suppression through undesired quenching of radicals
  \item diffraction limits
  \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}\hspace{.5cm}  % <--- space
\pause
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   Optimization by Two-Photon Polymerization:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item true 3D-Process (random geometries) 
   \item radical quenching avoided
   \item small excited spots\\
  $\Longrightarrow$ smaller structures possible
 \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Advantages of 2-PP to 1-PP}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
 \begin{columns}[t]
 \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
  Basic Problems of Single-Photon Polymerization:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item layer-by-layer type of manufacturing (limits possible geometries)
  \item suppression through undesired quenching of radicals
  \item diffraction limits
  \end{itemize}
 \end{column}
\pause
 \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
   Optimization by Two-Photon Polymerization:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item true 3D-Process (random geometries) 
   \item radical quenching avoided
   \item small excited spots\\
  $\Longrightarrow$ smaller structures possible
 \end{itemize}
 \end{column}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```