# How to have an image on the left-hand side and text (with mathematics) on the right-hand side which are horizontally aligned in beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

Doing a presentation with an image of a graph on the left-hand side and the mathematics behind the graph on the right-hand side and I want them horizontally aligned.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `columns` as in for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122084/minipage-space-between-two-columns-and-aligning/122085#122085 See also section 12.7 in the `beamer` manual.

Answer (score 3):

Example of `columns` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  A graph and the mathematics behind this graph:

  \begin{columns}[T]
    \column{.45\linewidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
      \datavisualization [scientific axes, visualize as smooth line]
      data [format=function] {
        var x : interval [-2:2];
        func y = \value x*\value x + 1;
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \column{.45\linewidth}

    \begin{equation*}
      y = x^2 + 1
    \end{equation*}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction This `\vfill` should not be here! I edited my answer...